# How can I read a secure string within a custom activity in Data Factory v2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I currently have a DFv2 pipeline which uses a custom activity and I am trying to figure out how to read a secure string passed to the custom activity.

The reason I want to do this is so that my custom activity may add this secure string as part of a request to an external API.

Here is a simplified version of my custom activity :

`{
    "name": "CustomActivity",
    "type": "Custom",
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "command": "CustomCode.exe",
        "resourceLinkedService": {
            "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "folderPath": "foldercontainingcustomcode",
        "extendedProperties": {
            "url": "sampleUrl",
            "apiKey": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "**********"
            }
        },
        "referenceObjects": {
            "linkedServices": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            ],
            "datasets": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "AzureBatchLinkedService",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    }
}`

Here is some sample custom code :

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic activity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("activity.json"));
        dynamic apiKey = activity.typeProperties.extendedProperties.apiKey.value;
    }
}
```

My question is : How can I achieve this since reading apiKey directly will just read the string '*****' ?

Answer (score 1):

for security reason, data factory will never return the secure string in any case.

if you want to use the key in your custom exe, you can keep it as encrypted plain string in the JSON, and use your cert or symmetric key to decrypt it in your code. or you can reference a Azure Key Vault so that you can access it in your code too.